# Javascript Menu like JQuery Mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, firefox-os

I'm working with Firefox OS, on customer requirements I can not use frameworks for JavaScript (like JQuery), ie everything must be html, css and JS.

I have to do the pull-down menu with the same side effect of "pushing the page" ([this one](http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/examples/panels/panel-swipe-open.html#demo-page)) we've seen in JQuery Mobile.

They know how I can do this effect?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic way of doing this is to create a div box (page) and set a z-index lower than the main page so its always behind the main page. Then using css you can move the main page up and down to reveal the page behind.

**CSS**

```
#page {
    z-index: 999;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:white;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all .5s ease;
}

.box {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left: 0;
    height:100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(#ddd, #ccc);
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    z-index:1;
}

.move {
    top: 0em;
    margin-top:10em;
}
.moveb {
    top: 0em;
    margin-top:0em;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
function doMove() {
 var element = document.getElementById("page");
 element.classList.remove("move");
 element.classList.remove("moveb");
 element.classList.add("move");
}

function doMoveb() {
 var element = document.getElementById("page");
 element.classList.remove("move");
 element.classList.remove("moveb");
 element.classList.add("moveb");
}
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/cut3y0sq/

Comment: Nice one. But make sure it works with _fixed_ elements like toolbars. Fixed elements lose their position when transition is applied to their parent/wrapping div.

Comment: That's true, fixed position opens a new can of worms. You could get around it by having data-position:fixed with a style of position:absolute and have a wrapper as the main content. scroll performance looks ok at least on chrome for Android. I guess in a webview it might it not be as good, but i need to check.  Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/uajhbfa8/