# Responsive jQuery Mobile header buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got the following problem with my header section in my jquery mobile application:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
<div data-role="footer" class="ui-bar">
            <a href="#searchpage" data-role="button" data-icon="search" style="border-right:1px solid #0E6251;">Search</a>
            <a href="#sellbookpage" data-role="button" id="ContactSellButton" data-icon="dollar" style="border-right:1px solid #0E6251;">Sell</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="email">Contact Us</a>

            <div id='ContactUsProfileButtons' class='ui-btn-right' style="display: flex;">  
                <a data-icon='home' href="#profilepage"  data-role='button' style="border-right:1px solid #0E6251;">Profile</a>
                <a data-icon='forward' onclick='LogOut()' data-role='button'>Log Out</a>
            </div>
```

Ideally I would like the buttons to condense into a drop down menu as seen with twitter bootstrap. But I can't seem to get this right. Does jquery mobile a) not cater for this? b) if not how can I fix the problem?

Note for the code I followed this [link](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/docs/toolbars/docs-footers.html). I'm aware I'm using a footer class here but I simply did this to have the buttons be formatted next to each other and have the freedom of moving them around with out having to worry about  tags.

```
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at twitter bootstrap and If you are after a page pull down that reveals the menu i done a demo for JQM here [Javascript Menu like JQuery Mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27281305/javascript-menu-like-jquery-mobile/27284047#27284047)

I created another demo for a side menu than fades in and upon click. Simple and nice, like the one in a Gmail app.

The button to open and close is on left of the header, as i cant place it on it on the right, were it should be as fiddle places an overlay saying result there and its hard to get the click going.

**Demo** I'm using Font Awesome Icons as there is more variety for menus

http://jsfiddle.net/qd0cfvd6/

**HTML**

```
<div data-role="header">
<a data-iconpos="notext" id="panelleft" data-role="button"><i class="button fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
    <h1>Page Title</h1>
</div>

<div id="menu">
    <ul data-role="listview">
        <li><i class="icon fa fa-search"></i><span class="text">Search</span></li>
        <li><i class="icon fa fa-envelope"></i><span class="text">Contact</span></li>
            <li><i class="icon fa fa-book"></i><span class="text">Profile</span></li>
            <li><i class="icon fa fa-level-up"></i><span class="text">Logout</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu{
    width:100px !important;
    height: auto; 
    padding:10px;
    background-color:#fff; 
    position:fixed;
    top:47px;
    right:0px;
    -moz-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    -webkit-box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    box-shadow:-2px 0px 5px #aaa;
    width:100px;
    display:none;
}

.ui-btn-left, .ui-btn-right {
border: 0 !important;
background-color: transparent !important;
box-shadow: none !important;
}

.fa {
 font-size:18px;
}

.icon {
 margin-left:-14px; 
 font-size:12px  
}
.text { margin-left:20px !important;
font-size:12px }
}
```

**Jquery**

```
 $(document).on("click",".button", function(){
 $('#menu').fadeToggle("fast");  
});
```

**Result**

[image]

**Update 29 Dec 2014**

I came across this turtorial http://www.syncano.com/getting-started-reactjs-tutorial/ that uses React Js and Velocity that achieves an exact pop-in menu in a native Android App and did a quick demo just using Jquery and the Velocity animation Plugging http://julian.com/research/velocity/. Credit to the person that did the Original Demo and for the Velocity Code.

**Demo** Some Css need fixing for proper use, but it looks ok

http://jsfiddle.net/zhxc830f/

[image]